# Query Tuning / Optimization

Tags: sql, query-optimization, teradata

The Query is taking a long time to execute. Kindly help me optimize it or suggest what can be done. , I am using delete/insert to populate the data. Also, there is a single source table.
Kindly let me know how to optimize it further. Stats are also collected on tables. it is causing high spool usage and CPU resources also.

```
INSERT INTO PMD_STG_DS.UFONE_SNA_LINK_HR_DUR
SELECT A.MSISDN_A AS MSISDN_A,
    A.MSISDN_B AS MSISDN_B,
    CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_DIR = 'I' THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS IN_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_DIR = 'O' THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS OUT_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK IN ( 7 , 6 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WE_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK = '7' THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS SUNDAY_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 21 THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS OFFPEAK_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 21 THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS PEAK_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 23 THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS FRIENDS_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_PEAK_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_OFFPEAK_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 23 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_FRIENDS_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WE_PEAK_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WE_OFFPEAK_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 23 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WE_FRIENDS_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK = '7' ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS SUNDAY_PEAK_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK = '7' ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS SUNDAY_OFFPEAK_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK = '7' ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 23 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS SUNDAY_FRIENDS_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK IN ( 7 , 6 ) OR ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WE_OR_OFFPEAK_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 4 AND 8 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_EM_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 17 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_BH_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 17 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_EVE_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 7 + 1 AND 22 - 1 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_LN_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'I' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 17 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_IN_BH_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'I' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 19 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_IN_TR_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'I' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 20 AND 22 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_IN_LESR_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'I' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 7 + 1 AND 22 - 1 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_IN_LN_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'O' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 17 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_OUT_BH_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'O' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 19 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_OUT_TR_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'O' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 20 AND 22 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_OUT_LESR_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'O' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 7 + 1 AND 22 - 1 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_OUT_LN_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 17 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_N_BH_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 19 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_TR_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 20 AND 22 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_LESR_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 7 + 1 AND 22 - 1 ) THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_N_LN_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_TYPE = 'V' THEN A.CALL_CNT ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS CALL_CNT,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK IN ( 7 , 6 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WE_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK = '7' THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS SUNDAY_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 21 THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS OFFPEAK_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 21 THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS PEAK_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 23 THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS FRIENDS_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.CALL_DIR = 'I' ) AND ( A.CALL_TYPE = 'V' ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS IN_V_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.CALL_DIR = 'O' ) AND ( A.CALL_TYPE = 'V' ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS OUT_V_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_OFFPEAK_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 23 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_FRIENDS_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WE_OFFPEAK_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 23 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WE_FRIENDS_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK = '7' ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS SUNDAY_PEAK_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK = '7' ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS SUNDAY_OFFPEAK_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK = '7' ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 23 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS SUNDAY_FRIENDS_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 4 AND 8 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_EM_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 17 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_BH_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 17 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_EVE_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 7 + 1 AND 22 - 1 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_LN_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 4 AND 8 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WE_EM_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 17 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WE_BH_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 17 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WE_EVE_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 7 + 1 AND 22 - 1 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WE_LN_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK = '7' ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 4 AND 8 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS SUNDAY_EM_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK = '7' ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 17 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS SUNDAY_EVE_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK = '7' ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 7 + 1 AND 22 - 1 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS SUNDAY_LN_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'I' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 17 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_IN_BH_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'I' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 19 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_IN_TR_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'I' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 20 AND 22 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_IN_LESR_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'I' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 7 + 1 AND 22 - 1 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_IN_LN_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'O' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 17 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_OUT_BH_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'O' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 19 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_OUT_TR_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'O' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 20 AND 22 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_OUT_LESR_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN ( A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_DIR = 'O' ) ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 7 + 1 AND 22 - 1 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_OUT_LN_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 17 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_N_BH_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 18 AND 19 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_TR_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 20 AND 22 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_LESR_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR NOT BETWEEN 7 + 1 AND 22 - 1 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_N_LN_DUR,
        CAST( ( SUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.DAY_OF_WEEK NOT IN ( 7 , 6 ) AND ( A.CALL_HOUR BETWEEN 8 AND 21 ) THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE 0
    END )  ) AS INT ) AS WD_PEAK_DUR,
        COUNT ( DISTINCT
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_TYPE = 'V' THEN A.CALL_DT ELSE NULL
    END ) AS V_NBDAY,
        COUNT ( DISTINCT
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_TYPE = 'V' THEN A.WEEK_OF_CALENDAR ELSE NULL
    END ) AS V_NBWEEK,
        MINIMUM ( CAST( A.CALL_DT AS DATE ) - CAST( A.PERIOD_START_DATE AS DATE ) ) AS DIST_TO_PERIOD_START,
        MINIMUM ( CAST( A.PERIOD_END_DATE AS DATE ) - CAST( A.CALL_DT AS DATE ) ) AS DIST_TO_PERIOD_END,
        ( ( MAXIMUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_TYPE = 'V' THEN A.WEEK_OF_CALENDAR ELSE NULL
    END ) - MINIMUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_TYPE = 'V' THEN A.WEEK_OF_CALENDAR ELSE NULL
    END )  ) + 1  ) / CAST( MAXIMUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_TYPE = 'V' THEN A.WEEKS_CNT ELSE NULL
    END )  AS FLOAT  ) AS V_AMP_FREQ,
        ( ( MAXIMUM (
    CASE
        WHEN 0 = 0 THEN A.WEEK_OF_CALENDAR ELSE NULL
    END ) - MINIMUM (
    CASE
        WHEN 0 = 0 THEN A.WEEK_OF_CALENDAR ELSE NULL
    END )  ) + 1  ) / CAST( MAXIMUM (
    CASE
        WHEN 0 = 0 THEN A.WEEKS_CNT ELSE NULL
    END )  AS FLOAT  ) AS ALL_AMP_FREQ,
        ( ( MAXIMUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_TYPE = 'V' THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE NULL
    END ) - MINIMUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_TYPE = 'V' THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE NULL
    END )  ) + 1  ) / CAST( MAXIMUM (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_TYPE = 'V' THEN A.WEEKS_CNT ELSE NULL
    END )  AS FLOAT  ) AS V_AMP_DUR,
        STDDEV_POP (
    CASE
        WHEN A.CALL_TYPE = 'V' THEN A.CALL_DUR ELSE NULL
    END ) AS V_VOLATILITE_DUR
    FROM PMD_STG_DS.UFONE_SNA_HOURLY_AGG AS A
    GROUP BY 1,
        2;
```

Comment: You might try to materialize all the columns used in a MULTISET Volatile Table with a PI on (MSISDN_A, MSISDN_B) *before* aggregation and then agggregate against this VT.

Comment: Thank you @dnoeth. Can you write this query for me if possible? it would be learning for me.

Comment: It's two queries: `create volatile multiset table vt as (select MSISDN_A, MSISDN_B, all the other columns you need from PMD_STG_DS.UFONE_SNA_HOURLY_AGG) with data primary index (PMD_STG_DS.UFONE_SNA_HOURLY_AGG)` followed by your existing `select ... from vt group by 1,2`